# Suggestion to develop for tablet and phone?

Tags: android

This if my first time to plan to develop app for both tablet and phone.

I know that we can develop 2 different layouts inside `res` folder, but, for example:

> 1. For phone, in first screen, I want to list some menu that can navigate to next detail screen.
> 2. In tablet, in first screen, I want to display master-detail layout, so that the menu that are available will display details in detail.

Do I need to do two different logics in 1 Activity? What is the suggestion/best practice for it?

Comment: You can make 2 different Activities e.g: if(!isTablet){mainActivity};else{mainFragment};

Comment: I would suggest using two Fragments inside a parent Activity as shown in [this really handy guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). The guide shows how to check for whether the fragments can both fit on the screen (e.g. on a tablet) using a boolean `mDualPane = detailsFrame != null && detailsFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;`. Have a read, I think it is what you're after.

Comment: This one is enlightening : http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Using-Fragments-to-Build-User-Interfaces-in-Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use Fragments :

> Fragments make it easy to reuse components in different layouts, e.g.,
>   you can build single-pane layouts for handsets (phones) and multi-pane
>   layouts for tablets. This is not limited to tablets; for example, you
>   can use fragments also to support different layout for landscape and
>   portrait orientation on a smartphone.

here is a complete tutorial :
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html

Comment: Can't agree more! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Proper way for tablet and phone development :

```
if (!isTablet()) 
                            {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainPage.class);
                                this.startActivity(intent);
                                this.finish();
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainFragmentActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(i);
                                    this.finish();
                                }
                                catch(Exception e)
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
```

1) If not Tablet make Activity that have a drawer to manipulate to other activites

2) If isTablet make a detail layout with menu on left & container on right & replace different fragments

Comment: You got your answer, thats what important. Happy Coding.